# scanf doesnt read at the first time, but yes at the second

Tags: c

When doing this code, at the momento fo writing the option, it doesnt read int until i write it a second tiem (as you can see in the picture).

Some background: This code is opened after you have chosen the letter "r".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THp36.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void inicioUsuario() {
    int op = 0;

    printf("\n== BIENVENIDO ==\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("1. Reservar plazas.\n");
    printf("2. Mapa.\n");
    printf("3. Reservas.\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("INTRODUZCA LA OPCION: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%i", &op);
    do {

        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            printf("Numero 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            printf("Número inválido, inserte uno nuevo.");
            break;
        }

    } while (op >= 0 || op <= 3);

}
```

Comment: The do-while statement does not make a sense because within it the variable op is not being changed.

Comment: ttylerrdm, What is your exact input?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Even if i change it, or remove it, it doesnt fix my issue.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It comes from a previous sscanf() that takes a char which is the letter "r".

Comment: `scanf()` is really not very good at what it does. Use `fgets()` and parse.

Comment: @ttylerrdm - Your _picture_ doesn't show at all that the _option_ is read. - By the way, you use `fflush(stdout)` where it's not needed and don't use it where it would be.

Comment: @tadman `fgets(opcion, 10, stdin); op = atoi(opcion);` I've used this and still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't work" in more technical terms? What does your debugger say happens? `char line[1024]; fgets(line, 1023, stdin)` should work for sure. Trim the trailing newline junk if necessary.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `while` condition correct? The first part, `op >= 0` is confusing since 0 is valid and 1 is invalid yet they give the same results since both are greater than or equal to zero. The second part, `op <= 3` is confusing since it seems like that would be a condition that would cause you to *leave* the loop (since you have done a valid operation) rather than repeat it. Don't you want to repeat on *invalid* entries?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks, i've recently started programming in c.

Comment: @tadman `line[1024]; fgets(line, 1023, stdin)` --> `fgets(line, 1024, stdin)` or even better `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Viable as well. I just find way too many questions here lean really hard on `scanf()`. I can't recall a single instance of actually using it myself.

Answer (score 0):

try to add   scanf("%i", &op) after the switch statement so you can update the value of op in the while loop

Comment: Surely, just *moving* the `scanf` line to **before** the `switch` statement (but inside the `while` loop) would be simpler?